# false and (true && print('hi'))

Tags: php, logical-operators, short-circuiting

In PHP, why `false and (true && print('hi'))` evaluates to `false` and doesn't print `'hi'`? I know logical operators evaluates in short-circuit (they're *lazy*), but `&&` and parenthesis has [upper precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `and`, so `(true && print('hi'))` should be evaluated first.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: @CBroe it not the same.he is asking its not working with "true" when considering operator precedence.

Comment: @tan yes it is. The question _"does the condition after && (or `and`, as here) always get evaluated"_ gets answered with No for `false and something` - the `something` does not even get looked at any further than necessary. Operator precedence does mean what influence the operator has on the _result_ of the expression, not necessarily evaluation order of the individual sub-expressions.

Comment: Not sure why these hypothetical questions come up, if I wrote this code whilst working for a company I would expect to be kicked out, not voted up on SO.

Comment: @CBroe I read again and again to understand and digest this line "Operator precedence does mean what influence the operator has on the result of the expression, not necessarily evaluation order of the individual sub-expressions" an old school mistake. Thanks CBroe & Ricardo Pérez López

Comment: @NigelRen because people want to learn???

Comment: _"Operator precedence does mean what influence the operator has on the result of the expression, not necessarily evaluation order of the individual sub-expressions."_ @CBroe could you explain it a bit deeper, please? I always believed that the precedence dictates the evaluation order in an expression with two different operators, like the expression I posted. Thanks!

Comment: @ishegg, I believe the whole point of SO is for people to learn, no problems with that.  I just think that contrived examples which you (hopefully) will never encounter in the real world aren't (IMHO) good examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a good test example to play with to show the order of evaluation.

Evaluation is performed from left to right.

So to add something to your example...

```
<?php

// Evaluates Left to right
// Prints HI as (true && print('Hi') evaluates as TRUE
// Then the && FALSE is tested and it fails
if((true && print('Hi')) && FALSE){
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}

// Evaluates Left to right
// FALSE is evaluated and Fails
// No further checking is performed
if(FALSE && (true && print('Hi'))){
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

Note: I've not put in the AND vs && but you get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the following in http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php:

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code.

So, I tested the following:

```php
print('one') and (1 + print('two'))
```

and it prints:

```
onetwo
```

so PHP evaluates first the `and`'s left operand even `+` has higher priority and even using parenthesis. Interesting!

Thanks to everybody.